# What is the difference between using theme_table() and theme('table', array())?

Tags: 7, theming

I am using following code for theming..

```
theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows, 'attributes' => array('class' => 'view-all-frame')));
```

is the above format right?
Can 'attributes' be written above inside array?
Can I use theme_table() instead of theme()?

```
theme_table(array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows, 'attributes' => array('class' => 'view-all-frame')));
```

If they are same then does it affect the execution or anything related to it?

Similarly for **theme('item_list', array())** and **theme_item_list()**;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the same.

`theme()` function is some kind of wrapper for specified theme functions.

It's recommended to use `theme()` function instead of direct calls, so `theme('item_list', array())` is the right way.

Comment: is theme() format right ? Can attributes be used inside an array as i read that attributes is an reserved word or we can use attributes

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: is the above written theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows, 'attributes' => array('class' => 'view-all-frame'))) correct ?;

Comment: It will work, but the most proper code is `theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows, 'attributes' => array('class' => array('view-all-frame'))));`

Comment: can it simpler like that theme('table', array($header, $rows, array('class' => array('view-all-frame')));

Answer (score -1):

I think the function of theme_table and theme('table',array()) is the same. But the way you call the theme_table should be simple like that:

```
theme_table($header,$rows,array('class' => 'view-all-frame'));
```

Comment: No, `theme_table()` and `theme('table', array())` are not the same: The first calls a function, and the other one calls another function. Does `theme('table')` call `theme_table()`? It all depends from the presence of a module that set another theme function as "table" theme function.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thank you a lot. It'll help me understand more about the theme engine in Drupal.